# How can I move multi label right to left(one and the other)?

Tags: c#

I'd like to make moving label(right to left) and moving one and the other using c#.

I tried that. But not moving one and the other. I'd like to make such as this link.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56-pqKTOmtI)

```
lblScreenText.Text =  ss[index];
if (lblScreenText.Left < 0 && (Math.Abs(lblScreenText.Left) > 
lblScreenText.Width))
{
    lblScreenText.Left = lblScreenText.Width;
     index++;
}
lblScreenText.Left -= 3;
```

It is not work as one and the other.
When the first label is gone, the second label is start.

Comment: I guess an "if" statement isn't what you want. This will be executed once and only once. Perhaps use a `while`statement or something like that? Be careful that you don't run into an infinite loop

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: OH... Winform. I missed it. Sorry